# Getting '500' Error on APIs which were working fine till yesterday

Tags: circuit-sdk

I am getting Http 500 error since yesterday on all the calls to Circuit APIs.

Is some deployment work is going on? Please help me out. i have a demo next week.

Answer (score 0):

The circuitsandbox.net has been updated yesterday from 1pm EST and was offline for 2 hours. Did you test during that timeframe? I am not aware of any issues.

Comment: Its happening since yesterday and i am still facing the same issue

Comment: Can you provide more information. What is your client Id, what tenant and APIs are you calling?

Comment: i created a new bot as well and thn tried , its still not working. looks like its not a bot issue